# bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am struggling with linking all my files : css, JavaScript, bootstrap, images etc... On my local server works everything fine. When I upload to my web server I got this error...and I know it is because of the path that I have. It searches everything on my local. and I am using Codeigniter framework, so I have no idea what the path should be when I put it online.

Example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo css_folder_url('reset.css'); ?>" media="screen"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>web/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

This is how I need to link in this framework

Maybe I should change something in my host file :

andreaportfolio.local
::1 andreaportfolio.local --> maybe should be .com instead of local

[Photo about the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TWhk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually means that the specific file was not found. So either the path is wrong or the file is not present where you want it to be. Try to access it by entering source address in your browser to check if it really exists there. Browse the directories on the server to ensure that the path is correct. You may even copy and paste the relative path to be certain it is correct.

There can be a '/' missing as well, for example:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>web/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

could be

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/web/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Comment: @JustDoIt thanks, I think it is just not present where I want to be,...since on my local server it works everything totally fine, so it has to be the path

Comment: So it was my base_url that I had to set correctly and now it works fine:) thank you

Answer (score 1):

here there is how things should work in a small step-to-step guide:

- Create a folder called 'assets' in /wamp/www/yourProjectDirectory [In WAMP server];
- Edit the config.php in yourProjectDirectory/application/config directory as:

  $config['base_url']  = 'http://localhost/yourProjectDirectory/';

> ```
> <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
> ```

- Create the controller as Boots.php;
- Create the view file as samplebootstrap.css

> ```
> <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
> ```

- Go to the web browser and type:

http://localhost/yourProjectDirectory/index.php/boots/getBoots

Here you can find a dedicated thread on the topic:
https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-1146.html

Hope this could help,
L.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I will try